# ngx-datatable responsive issue

Tags: angular, datatable, responsive, ngx-datatable

## Background

So this is what we are trying to achieve - responisve behaviour such that the columns get disappeared on certain breakpoints and appear as a row details.

Since there is no such dynamic action from ngx-datatable we are following [responsive documentation](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#responsive) from their official doc.

## Problem

Following the above mentioned doc, we are defining breakpoints in css and the column disappears but that still takes certain width and has sorting icons.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VlNg.png)

## What is expected

I expect the columns completly disappears on certain breakpoint and other columns take available space.

I tried setting the entire column to display none but that does not work since the rows and columns are defined in component. I expect the columns completly disappears on certain breakpoint and other columns take available space.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.